# Cubic Root Behaviour R

Tags: r, square-root

In R, why does

`(-27)^(1/3)`

return `NaN`

whereas

`(27)^(1/3)`

returns 3?

As far as I understand, `(-27)^(1/3)` has the three solutions `-3, 1.5+2.5971i, 1.5-2.5971i` and `(27)^(1/3)` has the three solutions `3, -1.5+2.5971i, -1.5-2.5971i`. So, why return no solution for -27 and only the real valued for 27?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help('^')
```

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why
>   (-8)^(1/3) is NaN. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559
>   arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function pow
>   for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result in many
>   corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above is
>   mandated by the C99 standard. On many Unix-alike systems the command
>   man pow gives details of the values in a large number of corner cases.